# How to remove other organization contribution button from my activity profile

Tags: github, open-source

Today I created a new issue to a open source project. After submit issue I get their organization button to my activity profile. Named **@simple-icons**

[image]

I think after submission **Yes** to this question, it has been added to my profile. How can I remove it from my GitHub Activity Profile.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to remove the @simple-icons badge from your profile since

1. Opening an issue is considered to a valid contribution

You have two options:
1st: Contribute to the Project in whichever way you want to and have specified in the issue -> Open a Pull Request -> And Get it merged.
2nd: Close the Issue if you do not wish to contribute.

Since it is not possible to delete the issue in GitHub, the badge of @simple-icons cannot be removed as well.